# MySQL extratvalue range, output and parsing issues

Tags: mysql, xpath, syntax, extract-value

I'm learning MySQL. My query is follows:
`mysql>select extractvalue(1,1111111111111111111);` //  19 1's.
output:

```
`+-------------------------------------+
 | extractvalue(1,1111111111111111111) |
 +-------------------------------------+
 | 1111111111111111111                 |
 +-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`
```

But for 20 1's

```
mysql>select extract(1,11111111111111111111);
+--------------------------------------+
| extractvalue(1,11111111111111111111) |
+--------------------------------------+
| -7335632962598440505                 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the following show me different errors:

```
mysql> select extractvalue(rand(),5.5.28));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.28))
' at line 1
mysql> select extractvalue(rand(),version());
ERROR 1105 (HY000): XPATH syntax error: '.28'
```

Can someone explain me?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out these, it seems to work.

```
SELECT @rand := RAND();

select extractvalue(1,@rand);
```

However, `extract` doesn't seem to work and gives the error. Either way I have not managed to use `extract` or `extractvalue` to wrap `rand()`. Reason could be that `extractvalue` only returns **CDATA**. Your intention of application doesn't seem to be supported by this function. It's used on **XPATH**

for e.g.

```
Select allhttp://www.blablabla.com/error.php?id=null 
and extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(
select concat(0x3a,username,0x3a,password) from users)))
```

Found this to be interesting: [reference](http://kaoticcreations.blogspot.sg/p/xpath-injection-using-extractvalue.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However still I didn't understand much.